# My object moves with no keyframes

Tags: objects, transforms, keyframes

My sphere moves on its own. Whenever I place a cube next to it, it shoots off into the distance. When the cube isn't there, it just falls to the ground. I don't have any keyframes to my knowledge. What am I missing here?

I've just started learning blender so I imagine its something obvious. Ill attach my file.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have [*Rigid Body*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/introduction.html#introduction) *Physics* added to your objects.

If you do not want rigid body properties in your scene, you may remove the [*Rigid Body World*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/world.html#rigid-body-world) from the scene properties.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! that got if from flying away. If I wanted the box to impact the ball and move it, how would I do that without the Rigid Body World?

Comment: @blndrnovice please ask a new question for this. It still requires RB, but not how you were approaching...